# Django can't get to index page after I get to archive page

Tags: python, django

When I click 'Home' I expect that I will be redirected to `index.html`.

But after I visit my archive page (`journal.html`) (something like '/journal/2014/01' it's a query from db)

I can't go to index page or somewhere else, only on pages like `/journal/Year/Month` or `/journal/Year`.

Because when I try to get to `index.html` it redirects me to `/journal/Year/Month/index.html`

Why?

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^index.html$', index),
    url(r'^journal.html$', journal),
    url(r'^contact.html$', contact),
    url(r'^about.html$', about),

    (r'^journal/(\d{4})$', journal),
    (r'^journal/(\d{4})/(\d{2})$', journal),

    url(r'^auth.html$', auth),
    url(r'^logout.html$', logx),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # develop
    url(r'^Observations/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

my app/views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('index.html', {'user': request.user})
    else:
        return render_to_response('index.html')


def journal(request, *args):
    # print args
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        obss = Obs.objects.all()
        if len(args)>0:
            year = args[0]
            # print 'year', year
            obss = obss.filter(date__year=year)
            if len(args) > 1:
                month = args[1]
                obss = obss.filter(date__month=int(month))
                # print 'month', month

        ar_obs = Obs.objects.all()
        archive = create_archive_data(ar_obs)
        return render_to_response('journal.html', {'obss': obss, 'user': request.user,
                                                   'archive_counts': archive})
    else:
        state = "Please log in below..."
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('auth.html', {'state': state})
        return render_to_response('auth.html', {'state': state})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your `urls.py` or `views.py` that could cause that.

I assume if you type `{mysite}/index.html` into the browser it goes to the Home page as expected?

...and it's only when you are on a journal page and click the 'Home' link that it goes to the wrong url?

It sounds like you have a problem with the `href` of the links in your HTML... probably your link looks like: `<a href="index.html">Home</a>` ?

It is missing the slash in front so the url is treated *relative* to the current url, i.e. if you are on `/journal/2014/01` then clicking that link will take you to `/journal/2014/01/index.html`

The best way to avoid these kind of problems (and to avoid having to change all your templates if you change any of the urls in `urls.py`) is to name your urls and use [Django's `url` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Note that Django url patterns are [regular expressions](http://www.pyregex.com/) so you should be escaping the `.` character as `\.`

Also, taking advantage of regex, you only need one url pattern to match all the urls you want to accept for the `index` view. Same for the `journal` view.

So your `urls.py` would look like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^(?:index\.html)?$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^contact\.html$', contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^about\.html$', about, name='about'),

    url(r'^journal(?:\.html$|/(\d{4})(?:/(\d{2}))?$)', journal, name='journal'),

    url(r'^auth\.html$', auth, name='auth'),
    url(r'^logout\.html$', logx, name='logout'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # develop
    url(r'^Observations/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

And in your templates:

```html
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
<a href="{% url 'journal' %}>Journal</a>
<a href="{% url 'journal' '2014' %}>Journal: 2014</a>
<a href="{% url 'journal' '2014' '06' %}>Journal: June 2014</a>
```

I would probably make a further change, which is to use [named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) for your `journal` url:

```
url(r'^journal(?:\.html$|/(?P<year>\d{4})(?:/(?P<month>\d{2}))?$)', journal, name='journal'),
```

and update the view code accordingly:

```
def journal(request, year=None, month=None):
    # print args
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        obss = Obs.objects.all()
        if year is not None:
            obss = obss.filter(date__year=year)
            if month is not None:
                obss = obss.filter(date__month=int(month))

        ar_obs = Obs.objects.all()
        archive = create_archive_data(ar_obs)
        return render_to_response('journal.html', {'obss': obss, 'user': request.user,
                                                   'archive_counts': archive})
    else:
        state = "Please log in below..."
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('auth.html', {'state': state})
        return render_to_response('auth.html', {'state': state})
```

Also, rather than doing the `is_authenticated` check and subsequent login redirect manually in every view that needs it, you should look at using Django's `login_required` decorator:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: A good answer, but why would you want `.html` at the end of your URL's anyway? The lengths Django goes to to make it easy to support pretty URL's it seems a shame to ruin it like this. Am I missing some benefit or did you just chose to overlook it in the OP?

Comment: @PeteTinkler yes I agree it is ugly and unnecessary to have `.html` in the urls but I am assuming the OP has reasons for doing so (perhaps converting an existing website to Django)

Comment: Thanks. It was <a href="index.html">Home</a>. I change to <a href="/index.html">Home</a>. Thank you for advices!

Comment: @Victor if this provided the info you need please accept the answer